# Converting oracle form FMB's to XML

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm trying to convert oracle forms FMB files to XML. To do this I'm using forms developer 10's native Java tool. This works fine on my local computer but I'm trying to automate the conversion process on a server.

I've taken the main folder "Dev10G" from my forms install directory and added it to the server, but I'm getting the error that you can see in the screenshot. I'm trying to avoid doing a full install of forms developer on the server if I can help it. Has anyone any suggestion on what I might try next.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit the bat file in textpad.
You will then need to change the paths.
I you need extra help feel free to checkout my note how to do it here
https://oracleformsinfo.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/batch-script-for-fmb-to-xml-and-xml-to-fmb/

Comment: Thanks Mia, Those scripts will really help, unfortunately I'm still getting the error message in the picture above. Any ideas how to fix this?